# Find the value of $x+y$ if $x^2+y^2+10 = 2\sqrt2x+4\sqrt2y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $$x^2+y^2+10 = 2\sqrt{2}x+4\sqrt{2}y$$ then the value of $(x+y)$ is:
>
> a) $4\sqrt{2}$
> b) $3\sqrt{2}$
> c) $6\sqrt{2}$
> d) $9\sqrt{2}$

Please teach me its basics and how to solve it?

Comment: is it $2\sqrt{2x}$ or $2\sqrt2 x?$

Comment: just corrected it.

Comment: have you got your answer?

Comment: i have no clue about it. I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

We have $$x^2-2\cdot x\cdot \sqrt2 +(\sqrt2)^2+y^2-2\cdot y\cdot 2\sqrt2+(2\sqrt2)^2=10-2-8$$
 $$\implies(x-\sqrt2)^2+(y-2\sqrt2)^2=0$$

We know, if $z$ is real , $z^2\ge 0$

Comment: In OP, there is $2\sqrt{2x},$ not $2\sqrt{2}x$. But you might be right, he/she might have made mistake in typing.

Comment: @Avatar, let me confirm

Comment: see,my guess was right ;) (+1)

Comment: @Avatar, mine,too:) I don't think the earlier version has a simple answer like this